# Xerox scan to email and Exchange

Tags: encryption, authentication, exchange

We have two Xerox devices, a 7120 and a 7556 that we are trying to get to scan-to-email through our exchange 2010 server.

Currently they are able to do so to local recipients by not authenticating.  However if we want the devices to email to external accounts, it will have to authenticate.  The exchange server has some defaults in place, such as AUTH NTLM.  It appears that the Xerox devices do not support this.  The devices will do SSL and TLS.

Has anyone configured devices like these to securely authenticate to exchange?  Can we simply enable SSL auth on the exchange server and be in good shape?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You should just set up a receive connector for the copier. This way you can fully relay to other smtp servers without enabling additional features such as SSL auth. Remember, its always better to use whats there then to turn on additional features. Additional features = more security risks to manage.

Simple tutorial on receive connectors in relation to copiers: http://www.zerohoursleep.com/2010/02/allow-relaying-on-exchange-2007-exchange-2010-in-4-easy-steps/

... this was found by googling "exchange 2010 copier email". First link actually.

Answer (score 0):

In our environment, we have a receive connector which allows the device to relay. On the device, we have configure it with Hub Server's IP Address and have selected SSL/TLS for Connection Encryption.